# package com.google.ads does not exist import com.google.ads.AdRequest

Tags: android, netbeans, admob

I need to add AdMob to my android Netbeans project, and I have set it up in XML. I have added external jar GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar in the project. However when I tried to buil the project it show the following message:

```
error: package com.google.ads does not exist import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
```

How can i fix this.
[image]

Comment: what if you added the jar to the libs folder of your project?

Comment: Thanks [Eric Leichtenschlag](http://stackoverflow.com/users/953648/eric-leichtenschlag) for the answer. This is the solution. I didn't want to go back to Eclipse I love Netbeans, but I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and I think it is because you cannot import `com.google.ads` on its own. Try importing `com.google.ads.*` instead

Comment: I tried what you write and obtain the same, `error: package com.google.ads does not exist
import com.google.ads.*;`